# NHibernate Interceptor , auditing and logging to the database

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, audit-trail

I am using this piece of code as a part of my auditTrail Class but I am facing a stackOverFlow Exception when I try to log the changes to the database.

```
public void OnPostInsert(NHibernate.Event.PostInsertEvent @event)
    {
        if (!(@event.Entity is IAuditable))
        {
            using (ITransaction transaction = @event.Session.BeginTransaction())
            {

                if (@event.State != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < @event.State.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string propertyName = @event.Persister.PropertyNames[i];
                        if (@event.State[i] != null)
                        {
                            if (@event.State[i].GetType().Namespace.StartsWith("Averma.Fda.Domain"))
                            {
                                CompareIfOldStateIsNull(@event.State[i], Convert.ToInt32(@event.Id), @event.Entity.GetType().ToString(), @event.Session, false);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string auditEntry = "New value for " + SplitPropertyName(propertyName) + " has been added, the new value is " + @event.State[i];
                                @event.Session.Save(new AuditTrail() { AuditEntry = auditEntry, RelatedEntityId = Convert.ToInt32(@event.Id), RelatedEntityType = @event.Entity.GetType().ToString(), OperationType = Shared.Enums.OperationType.Insert });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                transaction.Commit();//the error occurs here 
            }
        }
    }
```

Could anyone guide me about how to resolve this issue and how can I log the changes to the database .

Comment: I guess your namespace isnt starting with `Averma.Fda.Domain`. So the `else` part is coming in which is, as it looks like, using an `Insert` which fires `OnPostInsert`. Never ending story. You should rather debug it and check where the unwanted loop is coming in. Should be easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not begin a new transaction and commit it inside the NHibernate interceptor because a transaction is already open and will be committed after the interceptor finishes its work, all what you want to do is to remove `using (ITransaction transaction = @event.Session.BeginTransaction())` and to remove `transaction.Commit();` and things will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you save your audit entry, it tries to create another audit log entry for the first audit entry and it repeats. The fix would be to check the target table is audit log table and not to create entry if it's the case.